# sending array index value to an int c

Tags: c, variables, casting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the value from array[i][] where i is the value that I need and want to store it in a variable that is going to be used for different things. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

This is what I have right now but I keep getting an error `error: expected expression before ‘]’ token`

```
int choice, startRow, startCol, peekCount=5, hagMoveCount=0;
char direction, hagDirection;
char maze[ROWS][COLS];
char hiddenMaze[ROWS][COLS];

startRow=maze[ROWS][];
    startCol=maze[][COLS];
```

At the same time I'm trying to get the column position

Comment: What are these supposed to mean? You need to specify both indexes of an array to get a value out of it.

Answer (score 0):

[2D arrays](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm) don't quite work like that. You should probably read up on how to use them.

You can't assign something to an entire row or an entire column of a 2D array.
You'd have to create your own function to handle that sort of thing:

```
void setRow(char maze[ROWS][COLS], int ROWS, int COLS, int targetRow, char value)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i< COLS; i++)
  {
    maze[targetRow][i] = value;
  }
}
```

> At the same time I'm trying to get the column position

Wut?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know how to evaluate arrays unless you either define the value in the second set of brackets, or in both of the brackets. `myArray[8][]` is not allowed, but `myArray[][8]` is (I tested this just now). The reason the compiler has problems with something like `myArray[][8]` is that it won't know if you're trying to make a 1 by 8, a 2 by 4, a 4 by 2, or an 8 by 1 array. You also need to put values in each of the array elements, otherwise they default to zero. That's easily done with a `for` loop or two.